# Why does pySpark crash when using Apache Arrow for string types?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, pyarrow, apache-arrow

In an attempt to get some outlier plots on large datasets I need to convert a spark `DataFrame` to pandas. Turing to Apache Arrow a simple run is crashing my pyspark console when casting x as string (it works fine without the cast), why?

```
Using Python version 3.8.9 (default, Apr 10 2021 15:47:22)
Spark context Web UI available at http://6d0b1018a45a:4040
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-1621164597906).
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>> import time
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import rand
>>> from pyspark.sql import functions as F
>>> spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Console_Test").getOrCreate()
>>> spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")
21/05/16 11:31:03 WARN SQLConf: The SQL config 'spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled' has been deprecated in Spark v3.0 and may be removed in the future. Use 'spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled' instead of it.
>>> a_df = spark.range(1 << 25).toDF("id").withColumn("x", rand())
>>> a_df = a_df.withColumn("id", F.col("id").cast("string"))
>>> start_t = time.time()
>>> a_pd = a_df.toPandas()
Killed                                                                          
#
```

Additionally I noticed that options such as `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.maxRecordsPerBatch", "5000")`are seemingly without effect as the web ui shows records of significantly more than 5000 being assigned to the tasks.

Any indication on how to resolve the pyspark console crash or more directly render large scatter plots would be highly appreciated - I have (unsuccessfully) tried to find a way to apply `Table.to_pandas(split_blocks=True, self_destruct=True)`but did not get the able structure from a spark `DataFrame`.

Comment: This snippet from [the docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/arrow_pandas.html) may be relevant, `Note that even with Arrow, DataFrame.toPandas() results in the collection of all records in the DataFrame to the driver program and should be done on a small subset of the data.`

Comment: You should be able to use [`pandas_udf`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/arrow_pandas.html#pandas-udfs-a-k-a-vectorized-udfs) for smaller memory usage.  That is what the `maxRecordsPerBatch` property is for.

Comment: @Pace thank you. I was not aware the limit only applied for pandas_udf. That explains the observed behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try to convert 33.5 mio (2^25) rows into a Pandas dataframe. This will lead to an OutOfMemoryError, as all data will be transfered to the Spark driver.

A way to find outliers would be to calculate the [histogram](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.histogram.html) for the column `x` and then filter down `a_df` to the relevant bins in Spark before creating the Pandas dataframe:

```python
hist = a_df.select("x").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).histogram(10) #create 10 bins
```

`hist` is a tuple of two arrays: the first array contains the boundaries of the bins and the second array contains the numbers of elements in each bin:

```
([1.7855041778425118e-08,
  0.1000000152099446,
  0.20000001256484742,
  0.30000000991975023,
  0.40000000727465307,
  0.5000000046295558,
  0.6000000019844587,
  0.6999999993393615,
  0.7999999966942644,
  0.8999999940491672,
  0.99999999140407],
 [3355812,
  3356891,
  3352364,
  3352438,
  3357564,
  3356213,
  3354933,
  3355144,
  3357241,
  3355832])
```

[rand](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.rand.html) creates uniformly distributed randon numbers, so the histogram in this case is not very interesting. But for real world distributions, the histogram will be useful.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to avoid the collection at the driver in some way while maintaining high-level features of pandas - 33.4m is only 1% sample of the full data. Perhaps in some future there may be a structure that behaves like a pandas data frame for users and leverages scale of spark. I will settle for spark in the mean time :)